# Show Tab Widget on each and every Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, tabwidget

Using Java, how can I show a Tab Widget on each and every Activity, even if that Activity is a subActivity of FirstActivity? If possible, please provide me with some code or examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use THis to start the new Activity

View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity("tab1", new Intent(this,tab1.class)
                                                             .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                                                             .getDecorView();

setContentView(view);

Comment: can you explain it little bit more??

Comment: getLocalActivityManager() method helps you get the tab activity alredy running and by adding this flag it clers all the previous activites in your stack.

Comment: mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_view_detail").setIndicator(res.getString(R.string.viewdetail),res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(new Intent(TabsActivity.this,Welcome.class)));                           if my code like this then how can i edit this for fullfill my purpose...??
          mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_updates").setIndicator("update",res.getDrawable(R.drawable.icon)).setContent(new Intent(TabsActivity.this,Welcome.class)));

Comment: Create Another GroupActivity and putExtra info along with your intent so when it gets it ,the group activity can check what tab should be opened.Use My code to open the new Tab.

Answer (score 0):

Create Another GroupActivity and putExtra info along with your intent so when it gets it ,the group activity can check what tab should be opened.Use My code to open the new Tab.